# What is the correct way of sending data when using named pipes?

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I want to send large data to another process through named pipes. In other words I have something like:

```
var dataToSend = new byte[1024*1024]; // some large data
NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyPipeName");
server.WaitForConnection();
server.Write(dataToSend,0,dataToSend.Length); // is it ok to send 1048576 bytes at once !??
```

do I have to split `dataToSend` in smaller chunks? Having this method works fine I am just afraid it might break in the future. Should I fix it?

### edit

On the client side I read the stream with a while loop doing it correctly I think. I am just worried about the sender side (in this case the server).

Comment: I probably would.  If only because a fail would mean re-sending a million bytes instead of a 1000 or 10,000.

Comment: +1 to your response thanks! what is the probability that it will fail if both processes are on the same computer? How long it takes to send 1024*1024 = 1MB on the same computer? I redder make my code stable I believe?

Comment: You are probably OK if you check it.  Like I said, it might make sense to break up a huge send (Gigabytes) so the re-send won't be as bad.  A million bytes would transfer in a few milliseconds; try timing it.  It will be very fast.

Comment: By checking I mean check that the send worked properly (right number of bytes sent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably OK if you check and verify the send. It might make sense to break up a huge send (Gigabytes) so the re-send won't be as bad. A million bytes would transfer in a few milliseconds; try timing it. It will be very fast.

Comment: +1 thanks! So if I do not break up the data worst case is I have to send all data again right? but eventually all the data will be received from the other end?

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, they either work or fail, meaning if the rec'd number of bytes match you are ok. (Accept it if you like it.)